# Get the current process (executable) name in Go?

Tags: go

What I am looking for here is the equivalent of C's `argv[0]`.

The `flag` package only gives access to command line arguments, but not the executable name.

While one can get the process with `Getpid()`, I haven't found something that will give me access to the whole command line. The `syscall`  command `GetCommandLine()` seems only to be available on Windows.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The traditional `argv[0]` in C is [available](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Variables) in `os.Args[0]` in Go.  The flags package simply processes the slice `os.Args[1:]`

Answer (score 33):

A better way as follows:

```
filename := filepath.Base(os.Args[0])
```

This will present only the application name and remove the path for you.

Answer (score 25):

Since Go 1.8, the answer is [`os.Executable()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Executable). Similar to other languages, there is also `os.Args[0]`. One important distinction is that `os.Executable()` is guaranteed to return an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't noticed that. Most of the time I want os.Args[0], but it's useful to know about os.Executable().